# Excel find width height depth in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make myself a function in excel which would automatically find values. But I'm stuck right now with nothing. The text is like this but not the same length always and structure.

Voltage: 12-36V
Power: 12W
Luminous: 800 lumens
IP rating: IP67
Dimensions: Width 72mm, height 98mm, depth 41mm
LED: 4x3W

I need to export from A1 to B1 Width in numbers (it can also be 72mm or 72), to C1 height etc. But I am stuck with the function to make.

Could anyone please help me?!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post a formula?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (try the search box above) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. Most importantly include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a formula try this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Width ",A1,1)+LEN("Width "),FIND(",",A1,FIND("Width ",A1,1))-FIND("Width ",A1,1)-LEN("Width "))
```

The formula searches for the term "Width " and extracts the all characters until the next "," .

Answer (score 0):

UDF.

Open VBA editor (ALT + F11).
Insert -> module

Copy paste the following code:

```
Function Regex(Cell, Search)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(" & Search & " \d+?\w+)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell)

    If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        Regex = Matches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
    End If

End Function
```

Save workbook as an macroactivated workbook.

Use the function like `=Regex(A1,"height")`

[image]